# How can I get the value of an HTML tag using JS

Tags: javascript, html

Okay guys, I do have another thread related to this one, however this is a new question.

I have this code in my HTML page:

```
<span class="licon liconspan">1</span>
```

Now how can I get the value of "1" into a JS variable?

Comment: 1 is itself a value .. explain in detail

Comment: How can I put it in a JS var to use it in my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually "1" is not a value of a tag, it is its content. In its turn, it is stored in `innerHTML` property of a certain element. For your particular case, you can access it like this:

```
var variable = document.querySelector('.liconspan').innerHTML;
```

Comment: it prints my console log to 'undefined'

Comment: I`ve commited a mistake, sorry. "innerHTML" with uppercase. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you must write the index `[0]` because the method `document.getElementsByClassName`
return an array

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName(".liconspan")[0];
var variable = element.innerHTML;
```